# django model can not create or save because of unexpected arguments

Tags: django, django-orm

[image]

I want to insert the row by these parameters.
but It failed because of the error wrote at Exception.

[image]

this is the model of Mart.

[image]

this is the form of Mart.

Comment: It should be `.is_valid()`, *not* `.is_valid`.

Comment: You can furthermore make use of `mart.save()`, so no need to work with `.cleaned_data` here.

Comment: Finally since your model has the same name as your form, your `Mart(name=...)` refers to the *form* not to the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In short**: please do *not* give your form the same name as your model. You here introduced a "*name clash*". This means that the `Mart` in `Mart(name=…, address=…, …)` refers to the *form*, not to the model.

Furthermore you write too much boilerplate code yourself. I advice to rename your `Mart` form class to `MartForm`:

```
# app/forms.py

from app.models import Mart

class MartForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Mart
        fields = ['name', 'address', 'tell', 'phone']
```

In your view, you can then call this with:

```
# app/views.py

from app.forms import MartForm

def register_mart(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MartForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('name-of-view')
    else:
        form = MartForm()
    return render(request, 'mobileWeb/admin/register_mart.html', {'form': form})
```

Extra things that were wrong:

1. it is `form.is_valid()`, not <s>`form.is_valid`</s>
2. you can save your form with `form.save()`, no need to wrap everything in a model object yourself; and
3. you need to redirect after a successful post to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).